# console.log of Array returns function item() { [native code] } in IE 10,11

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer

I am trying to debug an IE ajax issue. The data I collect in and store in an array call eachItem. It is then converted to a string using eachItem.join(''). But before it even makes it to this step I console.log the array and IE 10 and 11 return

```
 function item() {
   [native code]
 }
```

A console.log of eachItem.length returns 1. But I can't see the contents. I later am pushing this data over ajax and getting an empty array. But I was trying to start here first to see why IE doesn't seem to read my array.

Comment: `eachItem` is not an array. Somewhere you assigned a wrong value to it. It seems you assigned a function instead of calling it. Of course without a complete example, there is nothing we can do. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Hmm. That would make sense. Here is  a jsfiddle with the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/adibb/m0stnb7z/1/

Answer (score 4):

Internet Explorer (11) has a global function called `item` which is read only. After `item="foo"`, `item.toString()` still shows

```
function item() {
    [native code]
}
```

However it can be redeclared. After `var item = foo`, `item.toString()` shows

```
`foo`
```

Looking for use of `item` in the fiddle code finds

```
item = serviceTitleRow + eachService + trip_charge;
```

at line 98 without previous declaration. I suggest declaring `item` before use will likely fix the problem.

*FWIW*, Javascript strict mode treats assignment to an undeclared variable as an error and catches this error most of the time. Because function name identifiers don't have a separated name space to variable identifers, reassigning the value of a function name is allowed. However, strict mode in IE throws a different "assignment to read only property not allowed" error when trying to update the value of `item`, so strict mode may have helped catch this error earlier in multiple browsers.

Comment: microsoft still doesn't get that such behaviours will kill them

Answer (score 1):

Review your code to find if there is any variable that has not been declared and you are using that directly.
For Example:

1. abc={} may cause issue in IE
2. var abc={} will work

Answer (score 0):

I had a variable that was not defined with the var keyword. Solved my issue.