# $jsonObj data not being passed via ajax and POST on IE(11) only

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to pass data via post with ajax to my sendjs.php.

`jsonObj`    is not being passed in IE11 only (havent tested lower versions of IE but it works in Edge and all other browsers). `FormData` and `captchaResponse` are being passed though.

In 'Network' in IE 11 inspector the post data is:

`cart: [null]` and there are no errors displayed in console.

All other browsers it contains the data:

eg. `cart: {name: "130 Litre Polypropylene Soakwells", price: "$39.95", quantity: "4", total: "$159.80"},…]`

Live site here: [www.diysoakwells.com.au](http://www.diysoakwells.com.au) (you can add an item and checkout to test).

Have spent ages trying to find the cause and now I'm not even sure where to go from here to be honest, so any information would be appreciated and I will update the post with any info as requested.

app.js

```
$(function() {


    // Get the form.
    var form = $("#ajax-contact");

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $("#form-messages");

    var spinner = $("#spinner");

    var submit = $("#submit");

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        //display the cog animation
        $(spinner).removeClass("hidden");
        //hide the submit button
        $(submit).addClass("hidden");



        var jsonObj=[];
        for(i=1;i<$(".item-price").length;i++)
        {
            var items={};
            var itemname = $(".item-name").get(i);
            var itemprice = $(".item-price").get(i);
            var itemquantity = $(".item-quantity").get(i);
            var itemtotal = $(".item-total").get(i);
            items["name"] = itemname.innerHTML;
            items["price"] = itemprice.innerHTML;
            items["quantity"] = itemquantity.innerHTML;
            items["total"] = itemtotal.innerHTML;
            jsonObj.push(items);

        }

        console.log(jsonObj );

        var formdata = {};
        formdata["textbox"] = $("#textbox").val();
        formdata["name"] = $("#name").val();
        formdata["phone"] = $("#phone").val();
        formdata["email"] = $("#email").val();
        formdata["address"] = $("#address").val();
        formdata["grandtotal"] = simpleCart.grandTotal();

        var x = 
        {
            "cart" : jsonObj,
            "formdata" : formdata,
            "captchaResponse" : $("#g-recaptcha-response").val()
        };
        //jsonString = jsonObj+formdata;
        var y = JSON.stringify(x);
        console.log(y);
        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(y);
        console.log(result);


        // Serialize the form data.
        //var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "sendjs.php" ,
            //url: $(form).attr("action"),
            data: y,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                        if(response=="Thank You. Your order has been sent and a copy mailed to your inbox.")
                        {
                    //remove the button animation
                    $(spinner).addClass("hidden");
                    $(formMessages).removeClass("error");
                    $(formMessages).addClass("success");
                    $("#textbox").val("");
                    $("#name").val("");
                    $("#email").val("");
                    $("#message").val("");
                    $("#phone").val("");
                    $("#address").val("");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                    $(formMessages).removeClass("success");
                    $(formMessages).addClass("error");
                    $(spinner).addClass("hidden");
                    $(submit).removeClass("hidden");
                        }

                $(formMessages).text(response);

            }
        });
    });

});
```

sendjs.php

```
<?php
//Debugging
//ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
//error_reporting( E_ALL );

//replaces file_get_contents due to restrictions on server
function get_data($url)
    {
      $ch = curl_init();
      $timeout = 5;
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
    }

    //turn url_fopen on due to restrictions on server
    //ini_set('allow_url_fopen', true);

    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Perth');
    $time = date ("h:i A"); 
    $date = date ("l, F jS, Y");
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json,true);
    $captcha = $obj["captchaResponse"];
    $captcha;
    $secretKey = "scrubbed";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $response = get_data("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);

    //not used due to server restictions
    //$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);

    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);

    if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
        echo "Please Click on the Captcha";
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
    //echo $items;
    $name = $obj["formdata"]["name"];
    $phone = $obj["formdata"]["phone"];
    $email = $obj["formdata"]["email"];
    $textbox = $obj["formdata"]["textbox"];
    $address = $obj["formdata"]["address"];
    $grandtotal  = $obj["formdata"]["grandtotal"];
    $text = "<html style='font-family:arial'>
    <body>
        <h1 style='color:crimson;'>DIY Soakwells</h1>
        <p>This order was submitted from www.diysoakwells.com.au on $date at $time</p>
        <p>$name thank you for your order inquiry. Deliveries are normally every Friday, we will be in contact shortly to discuss your order and confirm a time.</p>
        <p>An invoice will be issued after delivery for payment via bank transfer.</p>
        <p>In the meantime if you haven't already seen it, you can take a look at www.soakwellcalculator.com.au to confirm the number of soakwells you ordered will be adequate.</p>
        <br>

        <h2 style='color:crimson;'>CUSTOMER DETAILS</h2>
        <p><b>Email:</b>\n$email</p>
        <p><b>Name:</b>\n$name</p>
        <p><b>Phone:</b>\n$phone</p>
        <p><b>Delivery Address:</b>\n$address</p>
        <p><b>Message:</b>\n$textbox</p>
        <br>

        <h2 style='color:crimson;'>ORDER DETAILS</h2>";

        $items_in_cart = count($obj["cart"]);
        for($i=0; $i < $items_in_cart; $i++) {
            $iname = $obj["cart"][$i]["name"];
            $price = $obj["cart"][$i]["price"]; 
            $quantity = $obj["cart"][$i]["quantity"];
            $total = $obj["cart"][$i]["total"];
            //display looped cart data      
            $items .= "<p>$iname x $quantity - $price <small>ea.</small> <b>Sub Total: </b> $total .</p>";
        }

        $final_total ="<br>
        <p><b>Total: </b>$$grandtotal <small>inc. GST</small></p>
        </body>
        </html>";

        //Email Content
        $body = $text.$items.$final_total;

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New order from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = $body;

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
        $email_headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
        //$email_headers .= 'To:' . $name . '<' . $email . '>' . PHP_EOL;
        $email_headers .= 'From: DIY Soakwells <orders@diysoakwells.com>' . PHP_EOL;
        $email_headers .= 'CC: orders@diysoakwells.com.au' . PHP_EOL;
        $email_headers .= 'Reply-To: DIY Soakwells <orders@diysoakwells.com.au>' . PHP_EOL;
        $email_headers .= 'Return-Path: DIY Soakwells <orders@diysoakwells.com>' . PHP_EOL;
        $email_headers .= 'X-Sender: DIY Soakwells <orders@diysoakwells.com.au' . PHP_EOL;
        $email_headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
        //$email_headers .= 'X-Priority: 1' . PHP_EOL;



        //validate Email
        $email_check = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        //Recipients
        $to = $email;

        if (mail($to, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers, '-forders@diysoakwells.com.au')) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            //http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You. Your order has been sent and a copy mailed to your inbox.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            //http_response_code(500);
            echo "There appears to be an issue with our server, please ring 0420 903 950 or email contact@diysoakwells.com.au.";
        }      
    }       
?>
```

Hope someone can give me some tips.

Edit: Added cart modal html

```
<!-- cart modal panel -->               
<section class="modal fade cartModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">

<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">

<!-- Modal Header-->                
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

        <h3 class="modal-title cart_summary">
            <b>Cart Summary</b>
        </h3>       
    </div>

<!-- Cart Modal Body -->
<section class="modal-body">
        <div class="checkout">

            <!-- Cart Items -->
            <div class="simpleCart_items"></div>

                    <!-- Cart Items Footer -->
                <div class="panel-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 cart_modal_btn">
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="simpleCart.empty();">Clear Cart</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 cart_footer_text">
                        <span class="total">Current Total: &nbsp;
                        <b class="simpleCart_grandTotal"></b>   
                        <small class=gst>Inc. GST</small>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3 class="cart_summary">           
                <b>Checkout</b>
            </h3>
        </div>

<!-- Customer Details Form -->
    <section class="details_form">
        <b class="invoice_info">Due to the custom nature of this service we do not take payment until your order is confirmed and the materials are delivered.</b>

        <b class="invoice_info">You will be emailed an invoice with our account details. Payment terms are 5 days from the invoice date please.</b>

        <p class="invoice_info">For payment we accept bank transfer and VISA / Master Card <small>(2.3% surcharge for credit cards).</small></p>

        <form id="ajax-contact" class="contact_form" method="post"> 
            <fieldset>                  
                <h4 class="contact_form_title">Questions / Additional Information</h4>

                <div class="textbox_container">
                    <textarea rows="5" style="overflow-y:hidden" class="textbox" name="textbox" id="textbox"></textarea>
                </div>

                <h4 class="contact_form_title">Customer Details</h4>    

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th><label for="name" class="cart_label">Enter Name</label></th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name Required" class="input" id="name" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><label for="phone" class="cart_label">Enter Phone Number</label></th>
                        <td><input type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number Required" name="phone" class="input" id="phone" required/></td>             
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><label for="emaile" class="cart_label">Enter Email</label></th>
                        <td><input type="email" placeholder="Email Required" name="emaile" class="input" id="emaile" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>                            
                        <th><label for="address" class="cart_label">Enter Address</label></th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address / Suburb" class="input" id="address" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>

                <!-- captcha -->
            <div class="captcha_container">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfPjyMTAAAAANe_qucSV5ZFAuDNO4Ud524-NGoa" data-size="compact"></div>
            </div>


            <section class="fb_container">
                <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/DiySoakwells" data-layout="button_count" data-width="225" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
            </section>
            <br/><!-- css this -->



            <fieldset class="submit">

                <div class="formMessages submit_field"></div>

                <div id="spinner" class="hidden success submit_field"><i class="loader2"></i></div>

                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send" style="cursor:pointer" class="success"/>
            </fieldset>

        </form>
    </section>
</section>      


<!-- Modal Footer-->
<section class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal">Back to Shop</button>
</section>

</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->

</section><!-- /.main section -->
```

Simple Cart config

```
simpleCart({
//Setting the Cart Columns for the sidebar cart display.
cartColumns: [
//{ attr: "image", label: false, view: "image"},
//Name of the item
{ attr: "name" , label: "Item" },
//Quantity displayed as an input
{ attr: "quantity", label: "Qty", view: "input"},



    //Price of item
    //{ attr: "price", label: "Price", view: "currency"},
    //Subtotal of that row (quantity of that item * the price)
    { attr: "total" , label: "SubTot", view: "currency"  }
],
cartStyle: "table" ,
checkout: {
type: "SendForm" ,
url: "/php/sendjs.php" ,
method: "POST" ,




}

});

simpleCart.bind( 'beforeCheckout' , function( data ){
data.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
data.textbox = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
data.emaile = document.getElementById("emaile").value;
data.phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
data.address = document.getElementById("address").value;
});
```

Codepen link to simplecart.js

[Copy of simplecart.js](https://codepen.io/whispering_jack/pen/GveOjR?editors=0010v)

Comment: Still hoping for some assistance if possible.

Comment: can you provide the html so that I can test it on my laptop

Comment: Added cart modal html to answer, you can use the live site at www.diysoakwells.com.au as well. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: Added javascript simplecart.js (codepen) and simplecart config to question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

Your code here uses `items`, not `item`, and that works fine for me.  I checked your live site, which uses `item`, and found that code does *not* work, it exhibits the problem you describe.  I copied that live, broken code locally and was able to fix the problem as described below.

**UPDATE**

I stumbled on the solution (described below), without understanding it.  After more research, I've now found the cause of the problem:  [`item` is defined as a native function in IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms536460(v=vs.85).aspx).

- [Related question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390300/for-in-loop-in-ie11)
- [Related Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055781/internet-explorer-weirdness-function-item-native-code-what-does-it-d)
- [Related Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045983/console-log-of-array-returns-function-item-native-code-in-ie-10-11)

**How I stumbled onto the answer**

I copied your code locally and played around with it.  I noticed `jsonObj` was created OK, though the contents looked strange.  Likewise `x` was created OK, but after `JSON.stringify` your cart contents were lost.

`console.dir(jsonObj)` showed that it was an array of objects, but each object showed up as a function called `item` - in IE11 only:

[image]

In Chrome it is an array of plain objects.

The name of that function (`item`) seems strange, considering it is the name of the object you are storing your cart items in.  And `JSON.stringify` on a function will return `null` - so that could explain it.

Checking your code again I notice you did not declare `item` anywhere.  I tried just adding:

```
var item;
```

outside your `for (i=1...)` loop, and this solved it for me!  Cart contents are not lost by `JSON.stringify`, and devtools shows the cart and your other data is POSTed successfully.

Maybe `item` declared somewhere else (in SimpleCart?) as a function, and that's getting in the way?  **UPDATE** Yes this is exactly what is happening, though it is declared by the browser itself, not in any JS.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out right now. I actually did know about the item var being a native IE function which is why I changed it to items and uploaded it to the live site but it must be cached and hasn't changed even though it was uploaded a few days ago. Thanks for taking the time to delve deeper to really understand and solve the problem!

Comment: Yep that was it. Thanks again, it turns out I had forgotten I had combined app.js with another file so I had thought changing the function to items did not work when I tried it, but I had unknowingly edited the wrong file and would never have worked it out after initially dismissing it. Have added some documentation for the future, cheers your a legend!

Comment: Glad we cracked it! ;-)

Comment: Apparently you only just got the bounty? Apologies for the delay I thought it was awarded when I selected your answer.

Comment: NP :-)  [It has to be manually awarded](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), or if not it is automatically awarded at the end of the period.